# How can I have a checkbox checked by default, angular

Tags: angular, arraylist

I have a checkbox list brought by an array of an external procedure, what I want is that a specific data can be shown already marked by default.

This is what I have so far:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjXwL.png)

As you can see the code in the input section I have divided it into two due to being able to do different tests, but what I want is just a checkbox row and the value that says PCP is marked by default

```
             <ng-template #showGrid>
                  <tbody class="TableNota">
                      <tr *ngFor="let item of creditosList; let row_no = index">
                                      <td *ngIf="userType!==137" class="text-center">
                                          <input type="checkbox"
                                              class="chk"
                                              [id]="'credito'+ creditosList.DOCUMENTO_FAVOR"
                                              [value]="item.DOCUMENTO_FAVOR"
                                              (change)="guardarList(item,$event.target.checked)"
                                              *ngIf = "item.FORMA_PAGO == 'PCP'"
                                              checked = "true"
                                              />  
                                      </td>
                                      <td class="text-center">{{ item.DOCUMENTO }}</td>
                                      <td class="text-center">{{ item.CONTRATANTE }}</td>
                                      <td class="text-center">{{ item.MONEDA }}</td>
                                      <td class="text-center">{{ item.MONTO | number:'1.2-2' }}</td>
                                      <td class="text-center">{{ item.FORMA_PAGO }}</td>
                          </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </ng-template>
```

This is how I currently have it

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFpcs.png)

I have tried to put it this way but as you can see, the checkbox list disappears and only one is marked

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJv6X.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/45P0r.png)

The result I expect would be that only the value that says PCP is checked by default and the list of checkboxes appears.

Any kind of help I appreciate in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Remove the `*ngIf` as it will hide the checkboxes for all items with `FORMA_PAGO !== 'PCP'`
2. Bind expression `item.FORMA_PAGO === 'PCP'` to the `[checked]` input

   ```
   <input type="checkbox"
       class="chk"
       [id]="'credito'+ creditosList.DOCUMENTO_FAVOR"
       [value]="item.DOCUMENTO_FAVOR"
       [checked]="item.FORMA_PAGO === 'PCP'"
       (change)="guardarList(item, $event.target.checked)"
   />
   ```

Comment: Hello, I did what you told me and it could work for me, thank you very much, there is a way to disable it after the check, that is, it appears marked but disabled so that it does not allow unmarking

Comment: If you want the checkbox to be disabled when it is checked, you can assign a variable to the input element and use it in the `[disabled]` expression, e.g. `<input #cb type=... [disabled]="cb.checked" ... />`